# UIScrollView autoscrolls after I set contentOffset

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, ios4

I am trying to navigate through UITextFields while the keyboard is up.  I have an xib setup with a UIScrollView with textfields inside.  I have the contentOffset.y changing when a UITextField is set to the first responder.  The first two textfields react normally, but after that the scrollview will shoot past the selected text field, and will get progressively worse the farther down the list I get.  I have setup NSLog statements, and breakpoints which have shown me that when I first select the textfield, the correct y value is used, but then the scrollview's scrollViewDidScroll method is called directly after several times, running past the textfield.

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{  
  textField.inputAccessoryView = accessoryBar;
  int offset = 30;
  [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, textField.frame.origin.y -offset) ];
}

-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{  
  [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
}  

-(BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField*) textField {
  [textField resignFirstResponder]; 
  return YES;
}
```

I am running iOS 4.3 on xcode 4.1 lion

Comment: Are you doing anything in scrollViewDidScroll that would change this? Or are you setting the content offset anywhere else?

Comment: I am not using scrollViewDidScroll for anything besides printing the offset calls using NSLog."NSLog(@"scrollview:offsetY:%f height:%f", scrollView.contentOffset.y,scrollView.contentSize.height);"

Comment: Is your offset always 30? And definitely log the textField frames like Mundi said.

Comment: See the below link to getting help.

[Your question solution here ..][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7193787/keyboard-scroll-on-active-text-field-scrolling-to-out-of-view/7195882#7195882


Thanks,

Comment: The scrollView's contentOffset.y is always set to textField.frame.origin.y - 30

Comment: See the below link to getting help.

[Your question solution here ..][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7193787/keyboard-scroll-on-active-text-field-scrolling-to-out-of-view/7195882#7195882


Thnanks,

Comment: See the below link to getting help.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7193787/keyboard-scroll-on-active-text-field-scrolling-to-out-of-view/7195882#7195882


Thnanks,

Comment: ok, the link above worked, although I had to modify the code abit, the idea of the code worked.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7193787/keyboard-scroll-on-active-text-field-scrolling-to-out-of-view/7195882#7195882

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your `accessoryBar` is messing things up? The `inputAccessoryView` property is normally read only, so I assume you have subclassed `UITextField`. Try your code without the `accessoryBar`.

Comment: I commented out the accessoryBar assignment, and I get the same results

Comment: Did you also NSLog your textField frames? It sounds like those are perhaps in different coordinates... Everything as expected?

Comment: Here is some sample of the output
third field tapped on
    scrollViewDidScroll: scrollview:offsetY:0.000000
    textFieldDidBeginEditting: textFieldY:147.000000 30
    BMAG_KeyRing[5111:f503] scrollViewDidScroll: scrollview:offsetY:117.000000
fourth field
    scrollViewDidScroll: scrollview:offsetY:0.000000
    textFieldDidBeginEditting: textFieldY:206.000000 30
    scrollViewDidScroll: scrollview:offsetY:176.000000
    scrollViewDidScroll: scrollview:offsetY:177.000000
..x11
    scrollViewDidScroll: scrollview:offsetY:191.000000
...

Comment: I cannot see any textField frames. Try `NSLog(@"textField.frame: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(textField.frame));`

Comment: I tapped on the third and fourth fields with your NSLog results 'textField.frame: {{20, 206}, {255, 31}}', 'textField.frame: {{20, 265}, {255, 31}}', they match the xib frames exactly