# Focus on UITextField does not work

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

In my iPhone application I have a UIScrollView with several UITextFields.
Using BSKeyboardControls I have added Prev/Next/Done buttons to move between the fields. However, the focus on the selected field is not working, meaning that the text field is actually still under the keyboard although selected.
`becomeFirstResponder` is activated but just don't set the focus.
Any ideas what might be wrong?
Thanks
In the H file

```
#import "BSKeyboardControls.h"
...
@interface AddClientViewController : BaseViewController<UIAlertViewDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate, UITextViewDelegate, BSKeyboardControlsDelegate>
...
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *firstName;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *lastName;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *email;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *mobile;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *birthday;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *anniversary;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *street;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *city;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *state;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *zip;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;

@property (nonatomic, strong) BSKeyboardControls *keyboardControls;
....
```

In M file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
...
    NSArray *fields = @[ self.firstName, self.lastName,
    self.email, self.mobile,
    self.birthday, self.anniversary,
    self.street, self.city, self.state, self.zip];

    [self setKeyboardControls:[[BSKeyboardControls alloc] initWithFields:fields]];
    [self.keyboardControls setDelegate:self];
}

- (void)keyboardControlsDonePressed:(BSKeyboardControls *)keyboardControls
{
    [keyboardControls.activeField resignFirstResponder];
}
- (void)keyboardControls:(BSKeyboardControls *)keyboardControls directionPressed:(BSKeyboardControlsDirection)direction
{
    UIView *view = keyboardControls.activeField.superview.superview;
    [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:view.frame animated:YES];
}
- (void)keyboardControls:(BSKeyboardControls *)keyboardControls selectedField:(UIView *)field inDirection:(BSKeyboardControlsDirection)direction
{
    UIView *view = keyboardControls.activeField.superview.superview;
    [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:view.frame animated:YES];
}
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [self.keyboardControls setActiveField:textField];
}
- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    [self.keyboardControls setActiveField:textView];
}
```

The setActiveField in BSKeyboardControls

```
- (void)setActiveField:(id)activeField
{
    if (activeField != _activeField)
    {
        if ([self.fields containsObject:activeField])
        {
            _activeField = activeField;

            if (![activeField isFirstResponder])
            {
                [activeField becomeFirstResponder];
            }

            [self updateSegmentedControlEnabledStates];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll have to put your code here.

Comment: @Rushi - adited and added the code. 10x

Comment: if it goes into the [activeField becomeFirstResponder];?

Comment: @Guo - yes. as written below it also kind of scrolls, but not good enough...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're using a UIScrollView with UITextFields, you can use the [`scrollRectToVisible`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html) method for the UIScrollview, in a method that'd be roughly like this:

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [_myScrollView scrollRectToVisible:textField.frame animated:YES];
}
```

To do this, you'll need to make sure that the `UIViewController` is the `UITextFieldDelegate` of each of the textfields in the scrollview. You could do this in the viewDidLoad method of your UIViewController:

```
[textField1 setDelegate:self];
[textField2 setDelegate:self];
```

...and so on

Comment: Hi, done all of the above. Still not working. I feel something is wrong actually with the way I did the scroll view, but not sure what exactly...

Comment: In that case, I'd throw in some breakpoints into that code and figure out what methods are or aren't being called as you tap the prev/next/done buttons.

Comment: All methods are called :) I am over that. What I actually found out is that it works, just works bad (or I am using it wrong). For example if I choose first field and then scroll down to the bottom and press next - the next field is actually scrolled to! :) also for the next fields... BUT, the 3rd field and so on are scrolled and presented on the screen while being UNDER the keyboard :( so I probably need to scroll it better... How? ;)

Comment: sounds like your UIScrollView is covered up by the keyboard. Make sure to set the scrollview's frame to only include the space above the keyboard, and then have its contentSize include the textfields. You can find out more about resizing a UIScrollView to compensate for a keyboard in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7169702/how-to-resize-uitextview-on-ios-when-a-keyboard-appears

Comment: Thanks Bryan, I took the stuff from the link, well it moves now :) jumps too much but I guess I will need to try debug it...

Comment: I guess keyboard gets messed up for the field that is used the picker, need find something instead of UIKeyboardWillShowNotification for the picker...

Comment: Debug result - actually it gets messed when appears the picker view

Comment: finally I went for this solution:     [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,textField.center.y-60) animated:YES];
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7193787/keyboard-scroll-on-active-text-field-scrolling-to-out-of-view

Comment: please give me demo link of bskeyboardcontrols in scrollview.

Comment: This fixed an issue I had with BSKeyboardControls in a UITableview, thanks!